# How to determine which URL accessed the script

Tags: php, ip-address

How do I tell if my script was accessed as `http://localhost/myfile.php` or, for example, `http://222.22.22.22/myfile.php`? I need to get the `222.22.22.22` part as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For info about "http://**example.com:8080**/myfile.php" you've got the following options:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
"example.com:8080"

echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
"example.com"

echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
8080
```

If the server run on port 80 the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] won't contain the port number.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will hold the part of the request URI you're looking for

Comment: This should only return the host domain like `www.blah.com', and not the dir or page info (eg: /myfile.php).

Comment: @Tim That's the part he wants. Maybe I made it less clear when I cleaned up his post, sorry for the confusion; I edited it again to make it explicit. In the first revision he does specifically say '222.22.22.22'

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]
```

More info on all of the available $_SERVER variables are in the PHP reference at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php